# Splitting Date in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLHIg.png)
Hi, I Have a Index ['release_date'] in a format of month,date,year , I was trying to split this column by doing

```
test['date_added'].str.split(' ',expand=True) #code_1
```

but now it's creating a 4 columns and what really is happening is for some reason is it is simply for few rows it's shifting columns therefore creating a 4th column
[code_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcQ0f.png)
[This is the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCY7e.png)

I tried splitting ['release_date'], I am expecting it to be splitted into 3 rows but for some reason few rows are being shifting to other column.

if someone wants to inspect that dataframe you can use google colab for it,
`!gdown 1x-_Kq9qYrybB9-DxJHoeVlPabmAm6xbQ`

Comment: What do you want as a final result?

Comment: Separate month and number, second year?

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili i just bascially want 3 columns namely date ,month and year but again I am not getting it because it adding a 4th column for some reason

Comment: Using split is an incorrect method. I will write it correctly and send it to you.

Comment: DatetimeIndex is used to work on dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_added']).day
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_added']).month
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_added']).year
```

Comment: Thank you so much man , can't beleive it was this simple (╥﹏╥)

Comment: please rate me :) score

Comment: Need 15 rep for that

Answer (score 0):

```
day, month, year = zip(*[(d.day, d.month, d.year) for d in df['date_added']])
df  df.assign(day = day, month = month, year = year)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?